# Use AJAX to handle array of IDs coming as NULL C# and JS

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

I am trying to take array from string on server side ,but the IDs that I am waiting for are coming as NULL. Please , advice regarding the provided source code above. I am not sure how to handle them in the scope of CompareReturnAllResults(.....).

```
    function compareFilesResult(whlIDs) {
    var result = 0;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax/CompareReturnAllResults',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        data: { ID: whlIDs },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data != null) {
                return result;
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            return result;
        },
        fail: function (data) {
            return result;
        }
    });
}





    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CompareReturnAllResults(string [] _IDs)
    {
        List<Common.Utilities.CompareFilesResult> result = new List<Common.Utilities.CompareFilesResult>();
        foreach (var id in _IDs)
        {
            var whl = WHLConfig.Caches.WHLsCache.Where(w => w.ID == id).First();
            var diffResponse = WhlObjects.WHLMethods.CompareConfigs(whl);
            Common.Utilities.CompareFilesResult temp = new Common.Utilities.CompareFilesResult(whl.ID, diffResponse.CountDeleted, diffResponse.CountInserted);
            result.Add(temp);
        }  
        string diff = string.Empty;
        if (result != null && result.Count != 0)
        {
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(string.Empty, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have declared `string[] _IDs` so make sure in ajax call use the same. `data: { _IDs: whlIDs },`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have used `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`, it tells to server that we send a `json` object. For this you have to use `JSON.stringify()` method.

`contentType` is the type of data you're sending, so `application/json`; The default is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`.

`JSON.stringify()` turns a `javascript` object to `json` text and stores it in a string.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/ajax/CompareReturnAllResults',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ _IDs: whlIDs }),
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    success: function (data) {
        if (data != null) {
            return result;
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
        return result;
    },
    fail: function (data) {
        return result;
    }
});
```

C#

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CompareReturnAllResults(List<string> _IDs)
{
    //code
}
```

Another method is to use `traditional:true` property.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/ajax/CompareReturnAllResults',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    data: { _IDs: whlIDs },
    traditional:true,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data != null) {
            return result;
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
        return result;
    },
    fail: function (data) {
        return result;
    }
});
```

C#

```
public ActionResult CompareReturnAllResults(List<string> _IDs)
{
    //code
}
```

Comment: I tried but it is the same ,the IDs are coming as NULL again. I am not sure that I am handling them right in the scope of public ActionResult CompareReturnAllResults(string [] _IDs)

Comment: Try to use `string IDs` and then use `JavascriptSerializer` in order to obtain the array.

Comment: Another method is to use `List<string> IDs`.

Comment: Also, the names must match. Try this: `JSON.stringify({ _IDs: whlIDs })` instead `JSON.stringify({ ID: whlIDs })`

Comment: Please, write it as example how I can use here JavascriptSerializer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Sarah, please try now.

Comment: Again they are coming as NULL even if I take them as List. I am not sure how to use this JavascriptSerializer here.

Comment: Change ajax `request` type to `POST`, and in C# use `HttpPost` and will work.

Comment: @Sarah, i updated my answer with a new solution.For me it works perfectly.

Comment: @Sarah, please accept my answer in order to help other people.

Answer (score 2):

I think it looks like I need to set traditional to true.

Script:-

```
jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true
```

**First One:-**

```
 $.ajax({
       url: 'controller/GetArray',
       data: JSON.stringify({
          employee: arrEmployee
       }),
       success: function(data) { /* Whatever */ }
    });


****Second One:-****

$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "controller/GetArray",
     data: {employee: arrEmployee},
     success: function (data) { /* Whatever */  }
});
```

Model:-

```
public class Employee
{
  public int Id;
  public string Name;
}
```

In Controller:-

```
public ActionResult GetArray(Employee[] employee)
{
    // code here what u do
}
```

Hope Its Work !!

Comment: Unfortunately not working ,again IDs in the Browser are coming as string array ,but in the server side they are NULL in the list.

Comment: It is working with the example given from Alexandru-Ionut Mihai. Thank you too!